# retrieve and store data from european patent office and weekly updating it using php

Tags: php

I am trying to get patent data from European Patent Office using their OPS(Open Patent Services) web API. Any ideas about how the authorization and authentication will be done in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their site it says
 - Define your apps and handle authentication (using "OAuth")
So you'll want to follow an "OAuth in PHP" tutorial, there are many out there.

Comment: Tutorials are asking to send the consumer authorization credentials to different different urls. I couldn't understand what will be the url to which i have to send these credentials